# button that chages backgorund image according to onclick

Tags: android, button, radio-button, radio-group

I need to change some visible properties of a button once it has been clicked. The button is always the same one, it doesn't change. I need a button that is at the beging green and when i click on it, it should change to grey. if i click on it again it should go back to green and so on. Its one button that just changes color and text according to if it beeing clicked (even manytimes).

Do i need to use a normal `Button` or a `RadioButton` or a `RadioGroup`?

could you please show me also how to implement its function by code? thanks

Comment: A simple button will be fine. Set it's `onClickListener` and in the `onClick` implementation change the text and background. Write the code and post it here if you're experiencing any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Make a global boolean variable

```
boolean green = true;
```

Then use the following code to change color.

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(green){
                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                green =false;
            }

            else  {
                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                green = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i have done this, but it only allows me to change the backgroundresourse once! i want to be able to click the button many times and alwasys change it

Comment: Also you can use ToggleButton, if you just want on/off button features.

Comment: the ToggleButton feature is actually very good. but as im using this button in a custom listView row i nedd this button to be selectable seperatly from the whole row. im trying to implement the togglebutton but it doesnt allow me to detach this button from the rest of the view?

Comment: I suppose that by now you might have got answers to your problem. If so, then please mark this question solved.

Answer (score 0):

check out this

```
boolean flag;
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
        if(flag){
            button.setbackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
            flag=false;
        }else{
            button.setbackgroundColor(Color.GREY)
            flag=true;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: i have done this, but it only allows me to change the backgroundresourse once! i want to be able to click the button many times and alwasys change it

Comment: @Pheonix7 for that you can use toggle button

Comment: the ToggleButton feature is actually very good. but as im using this button in a custom listView row i nedd this button to be selectable seperatly from the whole row. im trying to implement the togglebutton but it doesnt allow me to detach this button from the rest of the view?